# Binary Operand '==' cannot be applied to two '[[CustomClass]]' operands

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a lot of complex data I'm trying to move around in my applications.  I resorted to passing my viewconroller a [[[CustomClass]]] object for one specific state, but the compiler won't let me compare the [[CustomClass]] objects inside it (e.g. arrArrA == arrArrB).

I  get the error whenever I try to check equivalency between the two. Why can't I use '=='? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does your custom class conform to the Equatable protocol?

Comment: @rmaddy I just tried, it says conforming to Equatable isa "redundant conformance of 'Spell' to protocol 'Equatable'"